# Excel, multiple if statements

Tags: excel

I'm in over my head on this one.
Can anyone write an if statement for one cell with the following conditions:

1. if BB>0, B6>0, BA<-.3, BA>-1.2  THEN O11-.1
2. if BB>0, B6<0, BA>.3 THEN O11+.1
3. Leave cell blank if neither condition is met.

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: for 1 and 2 do all conditions have to be met, or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(BB>0,B6>0,BA<-.3,BA>-1.2),O11-.1,IF(AND(BB>0,B6<0,BA>.3),O11+.1,""))
```

The above formula should do the trick. The only thing I'm having trouble understanding is what are BB and BA? Are they named cells? If not they are not valid cell references and could cause problems in the formula.